# Ocaml lwt never ending loop

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-lwt

I'm trying to write a terminal application with Lwt.
Basically as longs as my app is running, I need to watch the terminal for input with Lwt_io.read_line.

Is there a better way than the following (pseudocode) to achieve some kind of loop while my program is running?

```
while true do
  let _ = ignore (Lwt_main.run my_application)
done
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Every time all the threads from my_application have finished, the Lwt_main.run gets invoked again & again & again...

Are there other or better ways to handle this with Lwt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would typically write your main loop as a recursive function, which evaluates to a thread, then pass that thread once to `Lwt_main.run`. Here is a small example:

```
let () =
  let rec echo_loop () =
    let%lwt line = Lwt_io.(read_line stdin) in
    if line = "exit" then
      Lwt.return_unit
    else
      let%lwt () = Lwt_io.(write_line stdout line) in
      echo_loop ()
  in

  Lwt_main.run (echo_loop ())
```

This can be compiled and run with:

```
ocamlfind opt -linkpkg -package lwt.unix -package lwt.ppx code.ml && ./a.out
```

In rough terms, this is what happens in the above code:

1. `echo_loop ()` is applied in the argument of `Lwt_main.run`. This immediately begins evaluating `Lwt_io.(read_line stdin)`, but the rest of the code (starting with the `if` expression) is put into a closure to be run once the `read_line` completes. `echo_loop ()` then evaluates to this combination of an ongoing `read_line` operation followed by the closure.
2. `Lwt_main.run` forces your process to wait until all that completes. However, once the `read_line` completes, if the line is not `exit`, the closure triggers a `write_line` operation, followed by another closure, which calls `echo_loop ()` recursively, which starts another `read_line`, and this can go on indefinitely.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not thinking of this... Thanks for the extensive response!